# TDengine Assertion happen when I query

Tags: c, time-series, fuzzing, tdengine

When I fuzz the Tdengine in Linux, I got an assertion failure as following:

```
Welcome to the TDengine shell from Linux, Client Version:2.0.19.0
Copyright (c) 2020 by TAOS Data, Inc. All rights reserved.

taos> SELECT bool 't' AS true;
taos: /home/xxx/opt/projects/databases/TDengine/src/common/src/tvariant.c:38: tVariantCreate: Assertion `strncasecmp(token->z, "false", 5) == 0' failed.
fish: “./build/bin/taos -c test/cfg” terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

Please help if you know how to resolve it.

Comment: this needs alot more details and focus. What did you try? where's the minimal reproducible example? ...

Comment: The fuzzer found an input that violates an asserttion in Tdengine code. This can be an error in Tdengine, report it to it's maintainers.

Comment: @nevilad, thanks for your answer. Maybe I know what fuzzer you are using and how I can reproduce it?

Comment: The output from your question states that TDEngine `terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)`. Fuzzers save crashing inputs, you don't have to reproduce it, just open your fuzzers crashing inputs folder to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same SQL with a different version(**2.3.2.0**) did not see the crash but a syntax error returned instead so thinking the assertion issue getting fixed. I see your client has an older version **2.0.19.0**. Maybe you can try to update to later versions?

```
Welcome to the TDengine shell from Linux, Client Version:2.3.2.0 Copyright (c) 2020 by TAOS Data, Inc. All rights reserved.


taos> use test; Database changed.

taos> SELECT bool 't' AS true;

DB error: syntax error near "as true;" (0.002308s)
```